# What is a word that describes a male that tries to stop any fun thing a male does to a female

Tags: single-word-requests

I have this person who constantly stops me from doing fun things. For instance, I take a girls phone,I plan to give it back in a few seconds, the " fun killer" then goes overboard and gravbs my wrist twists it and takes the phone back and gives it to her. Again not doing anything terrible, all in good fun.What would a good word for this person be?

Comment: How does it make a difference that you're both male?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on their reasoning.

Comment: Please read the SWR tag description: you need an example sentence.

Comment: Perhaps the term for such a person is "gentleman."  I can think of several colloquial/anatomical terms for the prankster.

Answer (score 2):

A ***[spoilsport](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spoilsport):***

> - (informal) a person who spoils the pleasure of other people by his or her actions or attitudes.

(Collins)